# "phantom column" in R

Tags: r, calculated-columns

I did this:

```
reg1_v1 <- multinom(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = y1, model = TRUE)

r1_v1 = summary(reg1_v1)

mod = r1_v1$model

fit1_v1 =  fitted(reg1_v1)

y1_predict = cbind(mod, fit1_v1)
```

So what I did is try to combine the raw data used in the model with the fitted probabilities. There're 3 fitted probabilities columns in fit1_v1, call them prob1, prob2, prob3. Then I try to use these probabilities to do some calculations. However prob3 cannot be used -- it is showing up when I load the dataset and look at the numbers, but I can't call it by it's column header "prob3". It's like a "phantom column" in my data. For example if I do

```
ratio = y1_predict$prob1/y1_predict$prob3
```

It will say:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "ratio", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 563778
```

But I can use prob1 and prob2 as usual. Any idea why this happens and how to fix? Thanks.

Comment: You are saying: "combine the raw data used in the model with the fitted probabilities". Shouldn't you `cbind` the `fit1_v1` to `y1` instead of `mod`?

Comment: Where do the `prob1` and `prob3` columns come from? I don't see either of them in the model formula. I wonder if they are `figments of your imagination` rather than `phantoms`?

Comment: @paljenczy  Because there're NA values in y1 and no NA values in fit1_v1....therefore dim is different....

Comment: @42- that is in the fit1_v1, this fit1_v1 contains 3 probabilities, and that is how multinom() works....